# Error--->ASP.net website Administration tool .Please help me i can't create role, user and so on

Tags: asp.net

> Unable to connect to SQL Server database. at   System.Web.Administration.WebAdminPage.CallWebAdminHelperMethod(Boolean isMembership, String methodName, Object[] parameters, Type[] paramTypes) at  ASP.security_roles_manageallroles_aspx.BindGrid() at  ASP.security_roles_manageallroles_aspx.Page_Load() at  System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.ArglessFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o) at  System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) at  System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Please describe your problem a bit more in-depth. It's not clear what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Not much there to go on.
I'd say that you need to check your connection string to the SQL database - as the error message says it cannot connect.

This means that one of the following is true:

1. No connection string.
2. No SQL Server at the expected location (wrong connection string)
3. Incorrect login details for the SQL server and so connection is rejected.
4. SQL Server not running.

Check all of the above.
Try coinnecting to the database using either Visual Studio Server Explorer or SQLServer Management Studio.
If database access has been added by use of drag and drop from Server Explorer then you'll need to relocate the database using it and refresh the data objects.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Guthrie has [a guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx) on configuring the Membership providers. Make sure you follow the setup instructions for the database if you are not using the default SQL express database.